# Rails creating migration to add columns to table causes error when running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a model created called "users" and i created a new migration to add some columns to the  users table. Now when i run rake db:migrate, I get the error below b/c it's trying to create the users table again

```
$ rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users`.....
```

Why is it trying to create the table again?

Here's the command i used to create the new migration

```
$ rails generate migration AddDetailsToUsers home_phone:decimal cell_phone:decimal work_phone:decimal birthday:date home_address:text work_address:text position:string company:string
```

The new migration looks like this:

```
class AddDetailsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :home_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :cell_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :work_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :birthday, :date
    add_column :users, :home_address, :text
    add_column :users, :work_address, :text
    add_column :users, :position, :string
    add_column :users, :company, :string
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

20120511224920_devise_create_users

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :username,           :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Encryptable
      # t.string :password_salt

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

20120619023856_add_name_to_users

```
class AddNameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :first_name, :string
    add_column :users, :last_name, :string
  end
end
```

20121031174720_add_details_to_users.rb

```
class AddDetailsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :home_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :cell_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :work_phone, :decimal
    add_column :users, :birthday, :date
    add_column :users, :home_address, :text
    add_column :users, :work_address, :text
    add_column :users, :position, :string
    add_column :users, :company, :string
  end
end
```

Comment: From the output it looks like the error occurs during DeviseCreateUsers, not on your new migration.. do you have another (older) migration that already created the Users table?

Comment: Yes i do. But i thought i should be able to add a new migration as i did and running rake db:migrate should run only migrations that haven't been currently run.

Comment: The new migration doesn't even run; seems like you have two other ones that both try to create the users table (`DeviseCreateUsers` and an older migration). You should probably change `DeviseCreateUsers` to use `add_column`s instead of trying to create the table.

Comment: I have 3 migrations, only one has a create users declaration, the other 2 contain add columns. I've edited the question with my 3 migration files.

Comment: Okay.. the migrations you posted run perfectly fine. Does `rake db:drop && rake db:migrate` work? Backup your DB first if you need the data..

Comment: Yes db:drop and db:migrate work. I'm just wondering why rails is trying to recreate the table instead of only running the migrations that haven't been run.

Comment: Seems to me that the only possibility is that there is something wrong with the database you tried to use initially. Rails doesn't seem to know the table exists. Can you post the content of `schema_migrations`?

Comment: I already dropped the database and redid it. Someone else suggested that if the record isn't in schema_migrations table, means it would run again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails keeps track of the migrations in the "schema_migrations" table of your database. Unless there is an entry for "20120511224920", which is the Devise migration, it will attempt to run it again, which it appears to already exists.

You can add that manually to the table if that is the case.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I ran a rake db:reset so the only migration in there now is a new one. If i would have known about the schema_migrations table i could have at least checked that.

Comment: Although i can't tell for sure if this is what the problem was, i'm guessing that there was a record missing from the schema_migrations table.

Answer (score 6):

The error is saying that it's trying to run the original DeviseCreateUsers migration again and can't because the users table already exists.

To fix this, you can run the down migration for `DeviseCreateUsers` and then run migrations as normal. You can do that with:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20121031XXXXXXXX
rake db:migrate
```

Where `20121031XXXXXXXX` is the date stamp of the migration name. In other words, you'll have a migration named `20120410214815_devise_create_users.rb` and you copy the date stamp from the filename and paste it into the command. [Here's the Rails Guide on Migrations for reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

**Edit:** This is noted in the comments, but just a word of warning. Running the down migration for a table will lose any entries that table has. I assume you're running in development mode, so this shouldn't be a problem. If you're in production, you will need to take extra steps to backup the table data and reload it afterwards, otherwise you're going to have a bad day (or week maybe).

Comment: If i run the down migration though, that's going to delete my table and all the data in there correct? According to the guide you posted, i should be able to add a new migration and running rake db:migrate should be able to tell if any migrations have been ran and not run those ones this time.

Comment: You're right. I assumed since you were running in development mode that recreating the User table was acceptable. Rails should be able to tell what migrations you've run or not. I just read the comments on the other answer. Do you have two migrations that run `create_table :users`?

Answer (score 5):

Can you try make a fresh database and then migrate it again:

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:create:all
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I did a rake db:reset, and then ran rake:db:migrate, but that still doesn't explain why i couldn't just create a new migration and run it. Rails usually handles this just fine.

Answer (score 2):

So from what I have gathered from this:

- You already had a User model
- You have a version of this in production
- You ran a default rails generate devise:install
- You then ran rails generate devise User

I am hoping that:

- You use source control
- You check code in a lot

NOTE: If not, you are about to learn why you need to do so.

**Revert your code to before you generated Devise**

Hopefully, you can just create a new sandbox of a point right before generating Devise. If not, copy your project directory and do it by hand. The only other option is manually edit all the files that Devise generated.

**Rerun your Devise generation**

- readd gem 'devise' to your Gemfile
- rails generate devise:install
- rails generate devise MODEL

Make sure that model does not exist! If you don't you get into the problem you are currently having.

**Migrate current users from one model to the other**

If you can generate a script to completely move authentication information from your old user model to the new, good for you. If you are using a different hashing algorithm from Devise for your current authentication, then you are going to either invalidate all of their passwords and require your users to create a new password using a confirmation code in their email OR you could migrate users as they log in. The first method is clean, complete, and rude. The second method is ugly, incomplete, and silent. Choose your method however you like.

Edit: You could probably find a way to customize Devise to use your algorithm instead. That would probably be even better, but a little more work and fairly brittle.

Another thing is that your authentication model should not be overloaded with account data. You should have a model that only handles authentication which has_a account data model that stores whatever you might want to track about accounts.

Comment: Luckily i'm not in production at the moment, so i ended up just having to delete my db data, but i'm just wondering what would cause the create_table script to try and run again instead of correctly skipping it and running the new migration with the add_columns

Comment: Oh well then you do not need to migrate the users, but I would still seperate authentication data from account data. As for correctness, Rails assumes that you want to do everything in a migration. To use User as your authentication model you need to drop your old one from the database before you run the 'rails generate devise model' command.

Answer (score 2):

use up and down methods. It will be useful for rollback and running specific migration file.

Please follow the syntax..

```
  class AddDetailsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
      add_column :users, :home_phone, :decimal
      add_column :users, :cell_phone, :decimal
      add_column :users, :work_phone, :decimal
      add_column :users, :birthday, :date
      add_column :users, :home_address, :text
      add_column :users, :work_address, :text
      add_column :users, :position, :string
      add_column :users, :company, :string
   end

   def self.down
      remove_column :users, :home_phone
      remove_column :users, :cell_phone
      remove_column :users, :work_phone
      remove_column :users, :birthday
      remove_column :users, :home_address
      remove_column :users, :work_address
      remove_column :users, :position
      remove_column :users, :company
   end
  end


    In this case please try to migrate using version number.
```

Like rake db:migrate:down VERSION=version number    #version number is which version you wants to migrate.

Comment: Why didn't the up and down methods get created when i created a migration with something like this `rails generate migration AddDetailsToUsers....`

Comment: Hi. the up and down method will be generated in rails 2.2.2.

Comment: Rails 3.1 makes migrations smarter by providing a new change method. This method is preferred for writing constructive migrations (adding columns or tables). The migration knows how to migrate your database and reverse it when the migration is rolled back without the need to write a separate down method.

So it looks like you don't have to worry about having a def self.down as Rails is now smart enough to know how to roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you ran `rails generate devise user` sometime which generated `DeviseCreateUsers`. If you have already created User model and users table, you can delete the generated migration file from db/migrate.

Comment: But if i delete the generated migration, when i move to production and run migrations on a fresh database, i'm going to be missing some migrations.

Comment: I supposed that you already had another migration for creating users table.

Comment: I do have another migration for creating the users table.

Comment: Then I think you can delete the migration for DeviseCreateUsers safely. You can test it locally with a fresh database.

Answer (score 1):

Check for some environmental variables that might be supplying an unexpected value for the version of your migration.  I found [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70318/rake-dbmigrate-doesnt-detect-new-migration) on Stack Overflow (and forgive me if it is way out of date) where `db:migrate` was destroying the table, instead of applying an existing new migration.

They eventually found that an environmental variable was causing `db:migrate` to run with a version parameter of "0" which is functionally equivalent to `rake db:migrate:down`

Is it possible that your situation could be caused by the version being unexpectedly changed to include or match the previous migration `DeviseCreateUsers`?

Comment: I don't think so because all of the migrations have different timestamps on them

Answer (score 0):

just try

in the first file

```
create_table(:users), :force => true do |t|
```

this will override any other table

Comment: but that will overwrite my table correct? As you can tell from all the other comments, I'm trying to add columns to the db, without having to delete the data. Rails is capable of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said you used this command to create a new migration

$ rails generate migration AddDetailsToUsers home_phone:decimal cell_phone:decimal work_phone:decimal birthday:date home_address:text work_address:text position:string company:string

Im not sure if its just a typo but it should be "AddDetailsToUser" and not "Users". Just check again and we will be able to help you. This is for devise generated model. When you mention User, in db it looks for Users.

Ruby on Rails follow linguistic convention.table_name is Plural but model_name is Singular. You have to use model_name in the command you used.

If you want to use table_name then use this

rails g migration add_details_to_users home_phone:decimal......etc

Answer (score 0):

And if you need to do some dirty migrations manually:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :images, :name
  end
end

A.new.migrate(:up)
```